# Como carregar remotamente opções em auto complete utilizando Typeahead?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, autocompletar, grails, typeahead

Estava estudando o `typeahead.js` com `bootstrap 3`, e estou tentando fazer um auto-complete que faça uma requisição no servidor para trazer as opções da lista.

Esse é o plugin que estou usando:
  [GitHub Bootstrap 3 Typeahead](http://GitHub%20%20Bootstrap%203%20Typeahead)

Essa é a função que utilizo para criar o auto complete :

```
$(function(){
        var options = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: 'loadNameChoices',
                replace: function(url, uriEncodedQuery) {
                      return url + '?input=' + uriEncodedQuery
                },
            }
        });

        options.initialize();

        $('#nome').typeahead({source:options.ttAdapter()});
    })
```

Ao digitar uma letra no campo, a requisição é feita no servidor, que devolve um [json](/questions/tagged/json) com os nomes. Porém o autocomplete não funciona.

Qual é a maneira correta de implementar esse autocomplete remoto?

Meu back-end é feito com [grails](/questions/tagged/grails). E no front-end uso `bootstrap3` + [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

Esse é o serviço que devolve o [json](/questions/tagged/json) com os nomes. Esse serviço funciona corretamente.

```
def loadNameChoices(){
    render(contentType: "application/json") {
        service.loadNames(params['input'])
    }
}
```

Se eu faço simplesmente:

```
$('#nome').typeahead({
   source: ['TESTE','TESTE']
});
```

O autocomplete funciona. Creio que seja algum problema com o Bloodhound

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação usa?

Comment: Meu backend é grails. Front bootstrap3 + jquery. Adicionei o código do controller que recebe a requisição.